# Inspecting Python operation: how to get all decorators literally?

Tags: python, decorator

I'm inspecting code in runtime. I want to get all decorators a function/method is decorated with. For example, if it is `@classmethod` I want to get just the string: **"@classmethod"**, if it is something like `@path(MyClass.myop)` I want to get the string **"@path(MyClass.myop)"**.
I know, I can try to analyze the source code but it is tricky and I'm sure all this information must be stored somewhere and should be retrievable.
How can it be achieved?

Comment: are such functions/methods custom implementation or "C-based"?

Comment: @cards It is all, regular Python code, what makes the difference?

Comment: It's not. Decorator syntax is just syntactic sugar for function application.

Comment: @ardabro I was thinking an approach using [`getsourcelines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) and has a limitation to pure python functions. But, in this case is not relevant, sorry for the confusion. I was thinking for ex to `@lru_cache`... but of course you are not interested in its content!

Comment: What about `func = dec(func)` ones?

Comment: What exactly are you doing at runtime? What exactly do you mean by decorator? If I did `method = classmethod(method)` in a class body, should that count?

Comment: So, a "decorator" is a pattern, basically a callable that accepts a callable and returns a callable. The only thing you need for this in a language is support for functions as first class objects. Python has some sugar for the function definition statement intended to support calling a decorator on the resulting function object from that function definition statement.

Comment: The Python runtime doesn't keep track of which functions have been passed to other functions. Nor does it keep track of the use of the sugar, unless you inspect the source (you should probably use `ast` for that) which isn't guaranteed to be there. Or in Python.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are trying to solve? Why do you want to know this? What is the context? I suspect this question suffers from the [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga want to extract module "interface": functios, classes, and their members, together with docstrings, without function bodies.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I delete my answer because I don't have enough time to fix it at the moment. The way with `getsourcelines` should be a possible one, just missing an exhaustive case by case study of each possible type of method/closure

Comment: @cards I think what you are failing to understand is *that there is no way to know if a decorator has been applied* just by being given the object.

Comment: inspect.get_annotations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to commenters I realized that the task was hopeless, and in the meantime, I realized that this type of processing should be performed using **ast** module, where everything but comments may be tracked and extracted relatively easily.

So my answer to may question is: **use ast instead**.